# How to _.filter nested arrays to return a specific array

Tags: multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I am trying to _.filter a nested array in pure Javascript. I know I can flatten my array of arrays to make this easier BUT the point of the exercise is to see how underscore js functions work. I am unable to get the array of arrays to contain only the objects that have my gamepiece. When I run my code, I get the result below:

```
Array[8], Array[8], Array[8], Array[8]]
```

It should return only 4 items in each array. Here is my code.

```
var results = _.filter(gameBoard, function(row, index) {
   if (row[index].gamePiece !== "") {
      return row[index];
    }
})
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `_.map` on the top-level array combined with `_.filter` on each of the sub-arrays.

```
var results = _.map(gameBoard, function(row) {
  return _.filter(row, function(cell) {
    return cell.gamePiece !== '';
  });
});
```

This would return a list of lists, where each list has had all of its empty game pieces removed.

Comment: wow, thanks! that worked. I thought _.filter also iterated through the array like _.map. Why was it necessary to use _.map as well? I really like how the empty game pieces were removed.

Comment: Well, filter can remove elements but not modify them. Conversely, map can modify elements (i.e. return modified copies) but not remove them. Your problem was basically to make a new array with the same elements as the original, but where each element has been modified so as to have missing pieces removed (map). For each sub-array, filter got rid of the empties.